# Implementation of project facet jst.icefaces could not be found. Functionality will be limited

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, icefaces

I am getting the following error when trying to import a project in Eclipse:

> Implementation of project facet jst.icefaces could not be found.
>   Functionality will be limited

This project uses Maven 2, JSF 2 and IceFaces 2. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need the ICEFaces 2 Eclipse plugin. You can find details in [this "Creating ICEfaces Applications with Eclipse" tutorial](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Creating+ICEfaces+Applications+with+Eclipse). Here's an extract of relevance:

> ### [ICEfaces 2 Eclipse Plugin](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Creating+ICEfaces+Applications+with+Eclipse#CreatingICEfacesApplicationswithEclipse-plugin)
>
> Download the Eclipse plugin from http://www.icefaces.org/main/downloads/ under Tools Support -> Eclipse. Place the zip file in a local directory.
>
> [image]
>
> Start Eclipse. From the Eclipse main menu bar, select Help -> Install New Software... -> Add --> Archive...
>   Select the plugin (zip file) from your local directory, give it a name and click Ok.
>
> [image]
>
> Select the checkbox beside ICEfaces Update Site, click Next, accept Licenses and click Finish.
>
> [image]
>
> This will require a restart of Eclipse.

Comment: Do you know which library I need if the warning is _"Implementation of project facet jboss.m2 could not be found. Functionality will be limited."?_